# how to make python requests accept self signed certificate (with basic constraint CA = False)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, openssl, ssl-certificate

im trying to do a https get via python requests to a local server and I'm getting a
"certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate" error.

The server uses a self signed certificate and it has basic constraint CA flag as False. I tried using the request's verify option as well. it resulted in same error.

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Verification with openssl as well failed

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error cer.pem: verification failed
```

However When I tried with a different self signed certificate with basic constraint CA flag as True, I'm getting a self signed certificate error and if I use the verify option in python requests, its working properly.

```
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'
```

Any idea why the self signed certificate with basic constraint CA flag as False is throwing a different error and how to get it accepted by requests module

Comment: You can set [verify](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) to `False`.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to properly verify the certificate in this case. The underlying openssl library needs to have a root CA at the end of the trust chain, which means you can use a self-signed certificate but only with CA true. With `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` one could also use certificates with CA false as trust anchor, but this option cannot be set from within requests and is not enabled by default either.